# Decrypting 3des from hex data with a hex key

Tags: php, encryption, mcrypt, 3des, tripledes

I am trying to use the mycrypt php library to decrypt the following:

> **Key:** aaaaaaaabbbbbbbbccccccccdddddddd
>
> **Data:** b5057bbc04b842a96144a0f617f2820e
>
> **Expected Result:** Test123123

The data is encrypted with 3DES with the mode ECB. The code I'm currently working with decrypts the hex value to "e2119b734b5050e3" which translates to "â›sKPPã". I have tried using open ssl which is returning "False".

The code is as follows:

(PHP Version 5.3.3)

```
$key = 'aaaaaaaabbbbbbbbccccccccdddddddd';
$key = pack('H*',$key);

// DATA
$data = 'b5057bbc04b842a96144a0f617f2820e';
$data = pack('H'.strlen($key),$data);

// DECRYPT MCRYPT
$data = rtrim(mcrypt_decrypt(MCRYPT_3DES, $key, $data, MCRYPT_MODE_ECB), "\0");
$decryptedHex = unpack('H*',$data);

// DECRYPT OPEN SSL (RETURNS FALSE)
$result = openssl_decrypt($data,'des-ede3', $key);

// ECHO
echo $decryptedHex[1];
```

Comment: Oof. Your life will improve greatly if you just avoid mcrypt. https://paragonie.com/blog/2015/05/if-you-re-typing-word-mcrypt-into-your-code-you-re-doing-it-wrong

Comment: @pvg I have tried both mcrypt and openSSL. When using openSSL I receive a "false" response. I have added the code for this to the question.

Comment: Check the openssl php binding docs. You need to set some options for raw data

Comment: Also, padding info is missing. Your test string doesn't look block sized. How and with what parameters was this actually encrypted?

Comment: @pvg The data was encrypted using 3DES with mode EBC. I am not sure how exactly that process is done as it is through a third-party. I know that it has been encrypted successfully though, because i've used online tools such as: http://tripledes.online-domain-tools.com/ that have seemed to successfully decrypt the data.

Comment: @pvg I'm not sure what you mean by padding info. Do you mean that the key or data values need to be padded to match in length or something like that? Also, I have been unable to find any php binding docs for openssl as you suggested before. Do you mind providing a link to any of those documents?

Comment: These details are pretty important, though, to get decryption working. For instance, your mode to openssl is wrong - it's des-ede, that is '2 key' 3des.

Comment: That's right, for a block cipher, the data must be padded to match the block size of the particular cipher.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/131199/discussion-between-tony-and-pvg).

Comment: I was able to figure out the encryption params, it's 2 key 3des with zero padding. I've put the results in an answer, it successfully decrypts your testcase.

Comment: Slightly pedantic, but the key is always binary for (3)DES (as block cipher), hexadecimals is just a "common" way to represent the binary data that makes up the key. I've put "common" between brackets because for secret keys, the most common thing is *not to represent* the key to the user at all and leave it binary encoded, stored in a key store etc..

Comment: @matt that is odd. But a course question would probably not be missing the 3des variant and padding info.

Comment: @pvg It seems the openSSL constants "OPENSSL_RAW_DATA" and "OPENSSL_ZERO_PADDING" are not recognized. I assume this is an issue with our older version of php. Is there no way to decrypt this on our current version of PHP? Updating to a new version of PHP is unfortunately not possible for us as of now. Thank you for all your help this far.

Comment: @matt that question you linked to was actually asked by my colleague

Comment: There probably is but my PHP builds don't have mcrypt, and even if they did, the behaviour of the interface has changed over time - I don't even want to think about it or touch it. You should seriously start thinking about how you can migrate to a more recent version of PHP.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem here is that there is too much missing information - the exact variant of 3DES, the padding info. With a little fiddling with encrypting options, rather than decrypting one can try to generate the ciphertext to find the correct options. They turn out to be

```
openssl_encrypt($ptext,'des-ede', $key, OPENSSL_RAW_DATA | OPENSSL_ZERO_PADDING)
```

Where `$ptext` is `"Test123123\0\0\0\0\0\0"`

The ciphertext can similarly be decrypted via

```
$result = openssl_decrypt($data,'des-ede', $key, OPENSSL_RAW_DATA | OPENSSL_ZERO_PADDING);
```

You will need to upgrade to a more recent and supported (PHP 5.3 was released in 2009 and is no longer supported as of 2015) version of PHP.

Comment: Thank you! I tried this code on a more recent version of PHP and it worked. I have created another question where I am trying to convert this code to the openSSL command-line equivalent: [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41306800/decrypting-using-openssl-des-ede-from-the-command-line-with-zero-padding-and-raw). Please take a look if you think you could help.