# Decrypting using openssl des-ede from the command-line with zero padding and raw data

Tags: php, encryption, 3des, tripledes, php-openssl

I am trying to recreate some openssl php code in the command-line. I have been able to get the following php code to work:

```
$key = 'aaaaaaaabbbbbbbbccccccccdddddddd';
$key = pack('H*',$key);

$data = 'b5057bbc04b842a96144a0f617f2820e';
$data = pack('H*',$data);

$result = openssl_decrypt($data,'des-ede', $key, OPENSSL_RAW_DATA | OPENSSL_ZERO_PADDING);
```

**The Command I'm Working on (Ubuntu)**

`openssl des-ede -in encrypted-data.txt -out decrypted-data.txt -d -K aaaaaaaabbbbbbbbccccccccdddddddd -nopad`

**The Key**

The key that im decrypting with is the hex value: `aaaaaaaabbbbbbbbccccccccdddddddd`. Can this key be passed as hex?

**The Encrypted Data**

The encrypted data I am passing in the encrypted-data.txt file is the hex value: `b5057bbc04b842a96144a0f617f2820e`. The data should decrypt to `Test123123`. I have tried converting the encrypted data to binary and passing it through a .bin file without success. Should this data be converted to some other format before being passed?

**The Parameters**

I believe I am having an issue translating the php parameters `OPENSSL_RAW_DATA` and `OPENSSL_ZERO_PADDING` to my command-line call. I have discovered the option `-nopad`, but am unsure if it is equivalent to the options in php

Comment: This works fine. The key in your example is just wrong.

Comment: @pvg do you mean the key needs to be in another format? I am able to decrypt the data with that key in php.

Comment: No I mean you literally typed in in wrong. You have a typo. Cut and paste the key from the php code.

Comment: Thanks for that catch, however it is still not decrypting properly. Do you think I am passing the data in the right format?

Comment: I don't know what you are passing in as data. I was able to decrypt it with the exact invocation you have (and the correct key)

Comment: @pvg so I have tried passing the raw hex data in the file "encrypted-data.txt" as well as converting the data to binary and passing it in the file "encrypted-data.bin"

Comment: The raw binary data works fine. So the problem is in however you converted it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm only including this here since I can't format a comment and this question should probably be closed and deleted. This verifies the process works identically with the command line `openssl` utility

```
pvg /tmp ➤  more e.php 
<?php
$data = 'b5057bbc04b842a96144a0f617f2820e';
$data = pack('H*',$data);

echo $data;
pvg /tmp ➤  php e.php > in
pvg /tmp ➤  openssl des-ede -in in -out out -d -K aaaaaaaabbbbbbbbccccccccdddddddd -nopad
pvg /tmp ➤  cat out
Test123123%
```